# Why should I avoid creating .gitignore and README.md files from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I read online -and unfortunately I cannot remember from where- that some programmers suggest to not create the `.gitignore` and `README.md` files from `GitHub` when you are creating the repository.

**But why?**
I would love to know the reasons behind this thought. Does creating those files from GitHub cause problems to my project?

Comment: Well, unless you can find the source in which you read that, I'm afraid your question is too vague and will be closed (*unclear what you're asking*).

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises when you want to create a new repository on GitHub *to contain an existing repository*. Consider the following:

- You create a local repository with `git init` and commit some work:

  ```
  [master] A---B---C
  ```
- You create a remote home for it on GitHub, letting GitHub create some files:

  ```
  [master] Z
  ```

  In this case, GitHub creates a commit `Z` in which the `README.md` and `.gitignore` files are committed.
- You run `git push -u origin master` to push your local changes up to GitHub, but it fails.

Since your local copy lacks the commit `Z`, Git cannot accept your push as a fast-forward update.

You are now forced to do something like

- fetch `Z`, rebase your local copy onto it, and push again, or
- force push, which will cause that commit to be lost on GitHub.

There's nothing wrong with creating `.gitignore` and `README.md` in the new repository wizard *for new repositories*. In this case you will

- create the GitHub repository, letting GitHub create these two files, and then
- `clone` that repository to your local machine.

You'll end up with a local copy containing those files.